# После установки обновлений на Windows-10 появляется предупреждение о переполнении CD накопителя

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10

Есть ноутбук ACER Pentium четырехъядерный довольно новый (CPU N3540 покупал два с половиной года назад). На нем стояла Windows-8 после покупки она проапгрейдилась до Windows-10-64 Home Edition. Windows-10-64 периодически качает обновления. Недавно поставилось очередное обновление. Теперь система показывает версию Windows 10 Version 1803 и номер сборки 17134.48.

Но не все оказалось так уж хорошо. После установки этого последнего обновления проявилась неприятная особенность: в начале работы секунд через десять после включения появляется сообщение о том, что носитель CD диск D:\ переполнен и предлагается очистить лишние файлы на нем. Появляется панель очистки где все лишние файлы показаны как нулевые. Если согласиться и нажать ОК, то панель пропадает и больше не появляется до следующего перезапуска машины.

При этом в носителе CD диске D: не вставлено ничего.

Работать вобщем-то это не мешает но немного раздражает.

Как убрать это ошибочное сообщение, чтобы оно вообще не появлялось?

Comment: Лучше скачать [тут](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download/windows10) средство создания носителя и переустановить систему с нуля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перезапустите службу, отвечающую за диск.